# JDBC Logical replication across multiple PostgreSQL databases

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, replication

I know it’s possible to use the PostgreSQL driver to receive a stream of logical database replication operations for a single database via the PGReplication API.

But I’d like to receive events from *all* the databases in a postgresql cluster with just a single stream.

The primary motivation is to reduce the number of connections required for our use case; we can avoid consuming or managing 30+ connections per server if we can consume just a single stream of data for all databases. This would scale better across the many servers we run.

Is this possible in JDBC? Happy to consider alternatives to JDBC as well.

Comment: If you want to replicate all databases, then why don't you use phyiscal replication? I also don't think you can avoid this in JDBC because logical replication in the core works on a per database level, not on the cluster level. So neither JDBC nor any other interface would be able to do that.

Comment: I don't actually want to replicate the databases, I want to send notifications to my stack when particular tables change. I know this can be done with NOTIFY, but NOTIFY doesn't support two phase commit, and it is complex to manage over 60+ databases (2 clusters of 30 databases). There are certainly pros and cons, but I'd like to explore using logical replication if it can be done across multiple databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing PostgreSQL offers will let you do this directly, because a PostgreSQL backend cannot be connected to more than one database or receive changes from more than one database.

It doesn't matter if you use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`, logical decoding, or what, you're going to need one connection per database. Or you'll need some kind of aggregator/proxy that maintains those connections and provides a single stream to your app.

Consider:

- Having a per-db-server aggregator running on or close to the DB server, that has conns to all DBs on a server and provides a single event stream via Kafka or whatever.
- Examining whether an architecture with this many independent databases that you need to interlink for some purpose makes sense. Should you be schema-sharding instead perhaps?

The next version of pglogical (not PostgreSQL's built-in logical replication, a separate tool) will support feeding an event stream into Kafka, which you could then consume from your app. So that might be one option. Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers and work at 2ndQuadrant, which is the company whose tool it is.

Comment: Hi Craig, I was just looking at pglogical to see if it would fit the bill. Having pglogical post directly to Kafka would solve my problem, particularly if it could keep the output to strictly the primary key(s) of the affected rows. As I understand it, we would just need to deploy pglogical to each database in the cluster, but it wouldn't consume a TCP connection, which would be fine.

Comment: @DoctorEval It still needs an active backend connection and logical decoding session *per database*, so it affects `max_connections` etc. There's a connection there but it can be a unix socket or tcp, and is only local to the db server. I'm not that familiar with the new Kafka support and can't explain tons more.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about the backend connections (maybe I should be) so much as the fragility of our current solution, having something driven from within the database itself would help a lot. Our use case is specifically converting database updates to Kafka, so pglogical's next version sounds ideal. I did just have a look on github but it seems pglogical is being developed privately; happy to be a tester if you need one :). cheers

Comment: @DoctorEval I'm not allowed to publish pre-releases yet, you'd have to contact info@2ndquadrant.com. I don't know what the arrangements are for early access etc. I know some other people also feed data to different services, e.g. bottledwater, and I think people use wal2json too.

Comment: No worries, I’ve looked at bottledwater and am considering pg_recvlogical with wal2json as well. Thanks!